# Entity Framework: Updating a field to a null value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using stubs to update my entities and when the updated entity consists of columns that have values changed from non-nulls to nulls, the nulls are not persisted to the database i.e. the record continues to hold the previous non-null values.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void UpdateEntity(Entity e)
        {
            _context.Works.Attach(new Entity{ Id = e.Id });
            _context.ApplyCurrentValues("Entities", e);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Depends on what your relationship is, if you have a relationship, you need to make sure it's 0..1 and not 1 to many.

Comment: The values I'm trying to null are simple database columns (i.e. date/integer/varchar); although there are other entities that have a 1...many relationship with the entity, they're not being modified in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to assign `null` to these properties *after* you `Attach()`, not before. Perhaps `ApplyCurrentValues()` only copies non-already-identical properties? (I've never tested, but it would be reasonable if it did.)

Comment: Thanks Craig, I think this might indeed be the issue. I can't attach the entity before I trigger ApplyCurrentValues() because it would really mess up my repository pattern. To get around this, I've instead been forced to retrieve the entity and manually have the values of the updated-detached entity update the values of the retrieved attached entity before calling SaveChanges(). I'm all ears if there's a way to avoid retrieving the entity to update it.

Comment: You could consider using [ChangeObjectState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.changeobjectstate.aspx). That should mark the whole object as modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid loading entities using Attach. If you just get entity from DB, you don't have to bother with settings flags on nulled items:

```
var stage = Db.Stages.First(s => s.ID == someId);
stage.Notation = vm.Notation; // can be also null
Db.SaveChanges();
```